# Auto listing theme wordpress - can you edit the fields of listings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a truck listing page that shows trucks for sale.
I was looking a wordpress theme however they are all for cars, and obviously the make and models are different.

Am I able to change these fields on most wordpress sites and if so how or can anyone recommend an alternative theme?
Please direct me to the correct place to post this if it the wrong place.
I have looked at the following themes:
https://themeforest.net/item/motors-automotive-cars-vehicle-boat-dealership-classifieds-wordpress-theme/13987211

https://themeforest.net/item/automotive-car-dealership-business-wordpress-theme/9210971

Comment: Please update your question to include more information. Currently, everything is speculation as you do not list any themes you have looked at.

Comment: @MarkTruitt I have added the themes, apologies

Comment: Not 100% sure on what your question is really as they both show you can just import via CSV and both offer a demo where you can test them. So you literally can try them before buying.

Comment: They are all for cars.. my site is for trucks (lorries). I'm wondering can you edit the listing pages to add new fields on as trucks have additional fields to be added on a listing

Comment: Just glancing at  https://themeforest.net/item/motors-automotive-cars-vehicle-boat-dealership-classifieds-wordpress-theme/13987211 on the front end they had trucks listed. This is generally just data saved in the backend. Cars outnumber trucks in purchase numbers so most use them since more on the market for demos.